# difference between $model->foo and FindbyPK - yii

Tags: php, yii

I'm trying to understand the difference between calling variable within a model and also trying to find a specific dataset in a datatable. In my actionCreate I have

```
public function actionCreate($id)
{
    $model=new Recipient;
    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['Recipient']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Recipient'];
        if($model->save())
        {
            Recipient::model()->updateListId($id, $model);
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
        'id'=>$id
    ));
}
```

and in my model I've tried to do this

```
public function updateListId($id, $model)
{
    $model->list_id = $id;
    echo $id;
}
```

Why doesn't my model update like so? Should I be using findByPK?

---

Update

When I use

```
public function updateListId($list_id, $model)
{
    $id = $model->id;
    $model->updateByPk($id,array('list_id'=>$list_id));
}
```

then it updates. Could anyone explain what is happening here?

Comment: `public function updateListId($id, $model)` ? This is in a model? Since it's not static, why are you passing the `$model` variable to it instead of just using `$this`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have `$model = new Recipient`, you can use

```
 $model->id = $id;
 $model->save(); // Here you can pass array to save method to save only specified columns
```

instead of

```
Recipient::model()->updateListId($id, $model)
```

OR if you wish to do it with model function:

```
// controller:
$model->updateListId = $id;
$model->save();

// model Recipient
public function setUpdateListId($id) {
    $this->id = $id;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason that you don't need to use the term "set" when you are calling the  model for updateListId?

Comment: As well would you say that if I add 
"
$model->id = $id;
 $model->save(); // " 
That I should add this  above 

  if($model->save())
        {
            Recipient::model()->updateListId($id, $model);
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

If so, what is the point of the save?

Comment: @Stephen in Yii setters and getters works without `()` and prefix `set/get`. So setter `setVar($id)` can be called as `$model->var = $id`. And if you use `$model->id = $id; $model->save()`, than there is no need for `Recipient::updateListId`.